# RGBDSLAM .g2o file

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys:
I launched rgbdslam in ros,and save scene to .g2o file.
Now, I want to open .g2o how can I do.
I found openslam, here is g2o_viewer but I don't know how to use it.
help me,please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104761/rgbdslam-.g2o-file/) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if I get the question, but here's how I use it:

```
g2o_viewer file.g2o
```

Alternatively start it without parameter, then use File->load

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0